# Proper way to inject Session data before model save/validate in CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

#### Using CakePHP 1.3.6

I'm using a login-less authentication via a unique value as an URL param, so that when an "invited" user accesses a supplied link, I know who they are, and set some user information in the Session.

On this page is a form, with a parent and related child models (hasMany, belongsTo, all that).

Each child model has an 'agent_id' field (FK to Agent model, which is loaded upon accessing the page) that needs to be populated with an ID previously loaded in the Session.

Do I have to create a hidden input field for "agent_id" next to *every* child model form element group, or is there an easier way?

**Perhaps I can grab from the Session or something from within the Model/Behavior `beforeValidate()` or some such?** That would be ideal, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good practice (*in MVC pattern*) to call session values from Model. This value should be supplied by the action.

Creating hidden input is not great idea, because user can modify it.

So your code should be something like.

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    $this->Model->create();
    $this->data['Model']['agent_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
    if ($this->Model->save($this->data)) { 
         // success
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Yes, you can read sessions from Model, but its **not** recommended. Because  it actually breaks the MVC architecture. If you wont care much you can use

```
// in your Model.php
App::import('Model', 'CakeSession');
$session = new CakeSession();
```

**References**

1. [Using Session Vars in a MVC Domain Model library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704356/using-session-vars-in-a-mvc-domain-model-library)
2. http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/163bd9b60aa8757b/80163f0de8c54ad1?lnk=raot&pli=1
3. http://cakephp.1045679.n5.nabble.com/Checking-user-session-in-model-td1294422.html
4. [read more](http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=cakephp+reading+session+from+model)

Comment: you can include the session in the model itself.

check out miles' forum plugin for details: 
http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/forum-plugin

i disagree with ISH - if you are working with behaviors etc it might be justified.
Especially if you only READ the session (not modify it) there is nothing against using the session inside models/behaviors.

Comment: Yes @mark you can use(*read*) session. but its not recommended by good MVC practices. Please read references(*in Edit*) to my opinion.

Comment: I agree that it's not A Good Thing, but the way the project was laid out, I wasn't sure of a better method. The models are related to a parent, and being saved automatically via `saveAll()` on the parent. I do think it should be refactored or re-approached later, but thanks for answering directly in the mean time. I appreciate your help and feedback.  =)